# How to convert pu SI unit system in Matlab Simullink?

Tags: matlab, simulation, simulink

My simulink model

[image: My simulink model]

Everything is displayed in pu system. I want them in SI units. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to specify the unit in the block parameter for each block. That can be accessed by right-clicking the block and specifying the unit. More information here - https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/units-in-simulink.html

Another way is that after you are done with connecting all elements in your model (which seems to be the case), you can save it and update the existing model to have SI units. More information here - https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/update-existing-models-to-use-units.html

By default - the units should be SI units unless you changed the settings at some point, or are using a toolbox in which different units have been used.